# Lexical binding in a process filter

Tags: process, lexical-scoping, networking, lexical-binding

The code constantly prints `server-process: nil` instead of the server process name:

```
-*- lexical-binding: t; -*-
(let* ((port 1234)
       (server-process 'something))
  (setq server-process
        (make-network-process
         :server t
         :name "libbasecampel-oauth-http-server"
         :service port
         :buffer (generate-new-buffer "*libbasecampel-oauth-http-server*")
         :filter (lambda (_process _data)
                   (message "server-process: %s" server-process)))))
```

Can someone please explain why I can't access the server process from the filter lambda? Also, I would like to know how to do it, my goal being to kill the server when data arrives.

In case you wonder, the `_process` argument to the filter function is the client process, not the server one.

Comment: I don't know why lexical-binding at the top of your file does not have your desired effect, but you might want to try placing a backtick in front of `(lambda` and a comma before the `server-process` in the message statement.  In terms of the `let*`, you are only binding `port` and `server-process` and you are not using either of them in subsequent let-bound statements -- as such, it would appear that just `let` is sufficient and do not need `let*`.  In addition, you may be interested in trying `lexical-let` instead of `let` -- in that case, you may not need the backtick/comma.

Comment: FYI if I add `(message "%S" (process-filter server-process))` to the end of that outermost `let*` form, I see the expected `(closure ((server-process . #<process libbasecampel-oauth-http-server>) (port . 1234) t) (_process _data) (message "server-process: %s" server-process))`.  Do you see the same?

Comment: Have you perhaps written and evaluated this code in a buffer which does *not* have lexical-binding enabled?  (Just adding the comment doesn't do anything if the comment doesn't get processed.  Does the behaviour change if you re-load the file?)

Comment: FYI I've now tested it with process input, and with lexical-binding enabled your code works for me.

Comment: @phils: yes I do. The problem only appears in the filter function.

Comment: @phils: Could you please try again after you `(require 'server)`?

Comment: @DamienCassou Yes, that was of course the difference, as your Answer clarifies.  That recommendation to avoid hyphens in local variables in order to avoid name clashes is on the money (regardless of whether you are using dynamic or lexical scope).

Answer (score 1):

In a private email, [Christopher Wellons](https://nullprogram.com/) answered my question. The problem is that `server-process` is a special variable defined in server.el. Special variables are always dynamically bound. As a result, the filter closure doesn't close over the `server-process` variable. When the filter closure is evaluated, the `server-process` variable's value is the one from server.el, i.e., `nil` for me.

The fix is to use a different variable name.

Comment: I try to avoid local binding names with a dash for this reason.

Comment: I was curious and there are three symbols without dashes you shouldn't use for local var names as well: `obarray`, `debugger` and `noninteractive`